# JAX-WS truncates targetnamespace characters after dot causes class name collision (ends in /1.0, /1.1)

Tags: java, jaxb

We are autogenerating Java classes using JAX-WS 2.1.2 and maintain different versions of each xsd.
eg. happy_messages-1.0.xsd and happy_messages-1.1.xsd 
say the target namespaces are identical except one ends in /1.0 and the other ends in /1.1

This causes errors like:
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "dogs._1.someclass" is already in use

Looks like JAXB isn't parsing the number properly. (I would expect .1_0.class, .1_1.class)

I need to autogen these xsds as they are. Is there something I can do external to the xsds to get JAXB to generate the different versions of these classes in one jar?

thanks in advance!
-Dan

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post what I did to solve my issue.

I was unable to change the xsd files since they are an external interface to us but they could not be autogenerated due to improper handling of a targetNamespace which has version numbers in it as in /1.0/, /1.1/.

By using an external binding file I was able to specify a package name for each xsd.